# multiple conditions in if statement Go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

how can I have multiple conditions in an if statement inside a template?

I tried this code:

```
{{ if .condition1 && .condition2 }}
    <!-- SHOW SOMETHING -->
{{ end }}
```

But it doesn't work. (in fact it panics)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to use [function `and`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions), like:

```
{{ if and .condition1 .condition2 }}
<!-- SHOW SOMETHING -->
{{ end }}
```

Here's an working example: https://play.golang.org/p/g_itE5ggCM

Answer (score 69):

```
{{ if and (eq .var1 "8") (eq .var2 "9") (eq .var "10") }}
<!-- SHOW SOMETHING -->
{{ end }}
```

The parenthesis make the trick

Comment: This answer is much more elaborated than the one from @shizhz, +1

Comment: Thank you for this, I had the conditions with "and" but the more complex "eq" and "not" functions were not picking up the right parameters. The parenthesis are the important trick here! This should be the right answer.